# layout problem in android

Tags: android

I am creating fixed header and fixed footer for `RelativeLayout`. In the center part I am adding array of `WebView` when it come `ScrollView` it hide header and footer.

How can I avoid that?

This is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainrelativelayout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:background="@color/white"  
        android:id="@+id/mainlinear2"  
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="15dip"  
            android:orientation="horizontal"  
            android:id="@+id/linear5">
            <TextView android:text=" "
                android:id="@+id/txtwebservice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:textColor="@color/gray2"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_height="6dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView08"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/line"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView android:paddingRight="75dip"
                android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                android:text="Index"
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <TextView android:paddingRight="60dip"
                android:text="Last"
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="Change"
                android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_height="6dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView08"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/line"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:id="@+id/linear2"  
            android:orientation="horizontal">   
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView05"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:background="@drawable/down"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            <TextView 
                android:paddingRight="30dip"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"  
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtindex0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
            <TextView 
                android:paddingRight="55dip" 
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtlast0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtchange0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:textColor="@color/red1"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:id="@+id/linear3"  
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/up"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            <TextView 
                android:paddingRight="46dip" 
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"   
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtindex1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
            <TextView android:paddingRight="64dip" 
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtlast1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtchange1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:textColor="@color/green1"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:id="@+id/linear4"   
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/up"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            <TextView android:paddingRight="69dip" 
                android:paddingLeft="10dip" 
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtindex2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
            <TextView android:paddingRight="67dip" 
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtlast2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtchange2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:textColor="@color/green1"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:id="@+id/linear4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView04"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/up"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            <TextView android:paddingRight="61dip"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"  
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtindex3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
            <TextView android:paddingRight="65dip" 
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtlast3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12dip"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/txtchange3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:textColor="@color/green1"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_height="4dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView08"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/line"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="15dip"  
            android:id="@+id/linear5"  
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView android:text="Market data delayed at least 15 minutes "
                android:id="@+id/TextView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:textColor="@color/gray2"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/linear8"  
        android:background="@color/white"  
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView15"
            android:src="@drawable/quest_i"
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="200dip"  
        android:background="@color/white"  
        android:id="@+id/mainlinear3"  
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear8"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainlinear2"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<!--</ScrollView>-->
```

Comment: (For future questions, please note what good job @Octavian did here! Cleaning up that mess must have been quite some work. Note the "code" button!)

Comment: @Arjan: ew that is interesting. I mean I knew that the author is going to be notified anyway but I didn't know that the @reply only kicks in once. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why you are making it a single view....
Attach two imageView header and footer to the scrollview .

|ImageView|  |/ImageView|
|ScrollView| |/ScrollView|
|ImageView| |/ImageView|